# What to do when Author removed the hyperlink to the source but left a quotation?

Tags: discussion

It's about this post: https://serverfault.com/a/573357/468941

I edited it a while ago, adding source material, including a quote. My edit got approved but in the meantime the original author edited the post and removed the hyperlink to the source but left the quote.

I feel that it is unfair to quote something and neither marking it as a quote nor linking to the original content. I do not have enough reputation to comment yet, otherwise that's what I would have done.

EDIT: I just noticed that the original author actually did modify the quote a bit. I guess it doesn't qualify as quote anymore in this case. Nonetheless, my question remains: What should be done if a case like this occured?

Answer (score 5):

I think you don't have sufficient reputation yet to see the complete revision history of Q&A's. After [your edit](https://serverfault.com/revisions/573357/4) there have been two additional edits on the answer:

- [Revision #5](https://serverfault.com/revisions/573357/5) by another user with remark: *"clarified the meaning of the research by WISC by adding a related resource; deleting ZFS descriptions that are not relevant to this question"*
- [Revision #6](https://serverfault.com/revisions/573357/6) by the original author of the answer with remark: *"merge kubanczyk's comment on ZFS; this post is about ECC, so I don't elaborate on FS memory consumption beyond what's required to frame the ECC-ZFS article cited."*

Do those remarks sufficiently clarify why those edits have been made?

---

> I feel that it is unfair to quote something and neither marking it as a quote nor linking to the original content.

Indeed. Plagiarism is frowned on by our community, quotes and citations should be [properly referenced](https://serverfault.com/help/referencing).
Adding correct formatting and a link would be one suitable address, commenting or flagging the post for moderation attention are others.

Comment: I did have sufficient reputation, my problem was that I didn't notice that the author actually did modify the quote before I posted here. Anyway, thank you for the answer. I now know what to do should this problem ever arise again.

Comment: Revision history is visible without even being logged in.